# Highest rating armour?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was recently watching a live stream on twitch tv and I heard that there is apparently armour and swords that have a higher protection and damage stats than the Ursine mastercraft ones. Is this true? If anyone knows anything about these items than I would love to know about them!

Answer (score 1):

I have found no evidence to support that there is a higher rating armor set. I have come to the conclusion that there is none. I could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is yes. I currently have mastercrafted bear ursine. However i also have in my inventory Mahakaman trousers which are 85 armor while the mastercrafted is only 71. Don't know anymore.

Comment: Know where you found this?